# Quickly find out if pacemaker/corosync has quorum/is quorate

Tags: linux, monitoring, pacemaker, corosync

In a shell script, we currently call `/usr/sbin/pcs status cluster` and then `grep -qE` for `'Current DC:.*partition with quorum'` to find out if the cluster is fine.

I would like to know if there is a quicker way, because `pcs status cluster`  makes it query all nodes for their PCSD status, which takes time, about a second and a half, and I want to do this check before doing certain operations which are to be done quite often.

**Would `pcs status nodes both` and counting the number of online nodes be equally good for deciding if the cluster is functioning without issues?**

This takes ~2 seconds:
`pcs status cluster 2>&1 | grep -qE 'Current DC:.*partition with quorum'`

This takes ~0.2 seconds:
`pcs status nodes both | grep -cE 'Online: [a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+'`

(The cluster has 5 nodes, hence the three node names in the regular expression).

**EDIT:**

This takes ~0.02 seconds:
`corosync-quorumtool 2>&1 | grep -q -E '^Quorate:.*Yes$'`

Thank you **Matt Kereczman**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Corosync, you can use `corosync-quorumtool`:

```
# corosync-quorumtool -s
  Quorum information
  ------------------
  Date:             Wed Sep 27 07:16:18 2017
  Quorum provider:  corosync_votequorum
  Nodes:            2
  Node ID:          1
  Ring ID:          76
  Quorate:          Yes

  Votequorum information
  ----------------------
  Expected votes:   2
  Highest expected: 2
  Total votes:      2
  Quorum:           1  
  Flags:            2Node Quorate WaitForAll 

  Membership information
  ----------------------
      Nodeid      Votes Name
           1          1 172.16.7.100 (local)
           2          1 172.16.7.101
```

EDIT: And then just check that `Quorate` reports `Yes`.

Comment: Perfect! But I'll check for "Quorate: Yes", instead, or for "Quorate" amongst the "Flags:"
Quorum is most likely the number of votes needed to be quorate (showing 3 in my case).

Comment: @MattBianco: yes, that's definitely the better thing to check ;)

Comment: @MattBianco I updated the answer per your comment for the future people.